# iPad landscape orientation height/width issue

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iPad app that's only supposed to run in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft. I have set this in my plist, but all UIViewControllers are still allocated with a portrait frame, until they have finished launching. So any subviews I set in -init based on my view controllers' frames are wrong.

I have output self.view.frame and it's `0, 0, 768, 1024` while it should be `0, 0, 1024, 768` I also set my view controllers only to return landscape left:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it's rare that Apple will approve something with such a restrictive set of orientations on the iPad. Offering both landscape orientations will give you a better chance of being approved.

Comment: Hi Kenny, yes I realize this. This is an app I am doing for a client with iPads displayed in their retail stores, which means only one orientation is wanted. It will not be distributed through the App Store.

Comment: @jonydep No, not more than it looks like the view's frame isn't finally setup and given proper orientation after viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up subviews in -init, set them up in -loadView (if you aren't using a xib) or -viewDidLoad (if you are using a xib). When those methods get called, your UIViewController should be in the correct state and work as you want it to.

Comment: I have tried this, but same issue: (caller after super loadView) NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame)); outputs: {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}

Comment: On rootViewController's (window.rootViewController), self.view.bounds returns the correct sizing in the rootViewController's coordinate system. view.frame is in UIWindow's coordinate system which does not rotate with the device.